# Back navigation not reloading jwplayer in backbone js and rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, navigation, render, jwplayer

My app is a rails 3 app using backbone.js and jw player for playing a playlist of videos. The index_view for the videos has all the videos loaded into a playlist for jw player. My problem comes when I navigate away from the index page, let's say to the show_view for an individual video. When I click the browser's back button I get an error when the jw player tries to load again.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setup'
```

I believe the problem is that the template hasn't loaded the html element that the player uses to instantiate itself. That's my current theory. If you look in `index_view.js.coffee` you see that in the `render` method  I use the JQuery `$(document).read ->` method to load the player. If I remove that, the player doesn't load and I see the same error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setup'
```

This error can be reproduced simply by calling the jwplayer on a non-existant CSS id. ie `jwplayer('non-existant-id').setup(...)` would produce the same error. I'm pretty new to backbone but I would assume that the JQuery document.ready method has no effect after the initial loading of the index page. The DOM is never reloaded once I'm using the `#` routes, so when I navigate back to the index page, the id 'my-video' doesn't yet exist so calling `jwplayer('my-video')` produces an error. Is there any sort of `Backbone.ready` method?  :)

So here's some code, lemme know if you need anything else:

`index.html.erb` The rails view for videos

```
<div id="videos"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    // Blog is the app name
    window.router = new SeehearmeWebapp.Routers.VideosRouter({videos: <%= @videos.to_json.html_safe -%>, users: <%= @users.to_json.html_safe -%>, questions: <%= @questions.to_json.html_safe -%>});
    Backbone.history.start();
  });
</script>
```

`videos_router.js.coffee`

```
class SeehearmeWebapp.Routers.VideosRouter extends Backbone.Router
  initialize: (options) ->
    @videos = new SeehearmeWebapp.Collections.VideosCollection()
    @videos.reset options.videos
    @users = new SeehearmeWebapp.Collections.UsersCollection()
    @users.reset options.users
    @playlist = []
    @questions = options.questions
    for i in [0..@videos.length-1]
      video = @videos.models[i]
      versions = video.attributes.versions[6]
      images = video.attributes.thumbnails[0]
      question = @questions[parseInt(video.attributes.question_id)-1]
      if !(question == undefined)
        title = question.text
      else
        title = ""

      if !(versions == undefined)
        creator_id = video.attributes.creator_id.toString()
        @playlist.push {file: versions.url, creator_id: creator_id, gender: @users.get(creator_id).attributes.gender, question: title ,  image: images.url}

  routes:
    "new"      : "newVideo"
    "index"    : "index"
    ":id/edit" : "edit"
    ":id"      : "show"
    ".*"        : "index"

  newVideo: ->
    @view = new SeehearmeWebapp.Views.Videos.NewView(collection: @videos)
    $("#videos").html(@view.render().el)

  index: ->
    @view = new SeehearmeWebapp.Views.Videos.IndexView(videos: @videos, users: @users, playlist: @playlist)
    $("#videos").html(@view.render().el)

  show: (id) ->
    video = @videos.get(id)

    @view = new SeehearmeWebapp.Views.Videos.ShowView(model: video)
    $("#videos").html(@view.render().el)

  edit: (id) ->
    video = @videos.get(id)

    @view = new SeehearmeWebapp.Views.Videos.EditView(model: video)
    $("#videos").html(@view.render().el)
```

`index_view.js.coffee`

```
SeehearmeWebapp.Views.Videos ||= {}

class SeehearmeWebapp.Views.Videos.IndexView extends Backbone.View
  template: JST["backbone/templates/videos/index"]

  playerHeight = '360'
  playerWidth = '640'
  defaultVersion = 0
  playlist = []

  initialize: () ->
    @options.videos.bind('reset', @addAll)
    playlist = @options.playlist

  addAll: () =>
    @options.videos.each(@addOne)

  addOne: (video) =>
    view = new SeehearmeWebapp.Views.Videos.VideoView({model : video})
    @$("tbody").append(view.render().el)

  render: =>
    $(@el).html(@template(videos: @options.videos.toJSON() ))
    @addAll()

    $(document).ready ->
      player = jwplayer('my-video')
      player.setup({playlist: playlist,  width: playerWidth, height: playerHeight, skin: "/jwplayer/skins/six/six.xml"})

    return this
```

`index.jst.ejs`

```
<div class="video-container">
    <div class="row gender-toggle-row">
        <div class="gender-toggle-label span1">Show Me: </div>
        <div class="btn-group gender-dropdown-group">
            <button class="btn btn-extra-large gender-dropdown gender-dropdown-display">Women and Men</button>
            <button class="btn btn-extra-large dropdown-toggle gender-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <img src="assets/down-arrow.png" />
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu gender-dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="gender-toggle-element" href="#">Women</a></li>
                <li><a class="gender-toggle-element" href="#">Men</a></li>
                <li><a class="gender-toggle-element" href="#">Women and Men</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cinema-ribbon-sides"></div>
    <div class="cinema-ribbon"><h2 id="question-text" class="white centered-text">seehear.me</h2></div>
    <div id='my-video'></div>
    <div class="cinema-shadow"></div>
    <div class="cinema-controls">
        <a id="prev-video" class="cinema-prev"></a>
        <a href="#/71" role="button" class="meet"><div class="meet-btn-text">meet her</div></a>
        <a id="next-video" class="cinema-next"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
```

`show_view.js.coffee`

```
SeehearmeWebapp.Views.Videos ||= {}

class SeehearmeWebapp.Views.Videos.ShowView extends Backbone.View
  template: JST["backbone/templates/videos/show"]

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(@model.toJSON() ))
    return this
```

`show_view.js.coffee`

```
<h1>THIS IS A VIDEO</h1>

<a href="#/">Back</a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the JQuery `$.when(...).then(...)` a possible solution to this? I tried it and wasn't successful but maybe I'm putting the wrong stuff inside the `when()` method.

Comment: Kind of a shot in the dark, but can you try this: `$("#videos").html(@view.el); @view.render()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you render a Backbone view and add it to the page in this way:

```
$("#videos").html(@view.render().el)
```

You are rendering to a DOM element that is not yet added to the page.  Since you are trying to setup the jwplayer in `render()`, jwplayer probably can't find the element.

If you add the view to the page first, then render, it might work.

```
$("#videos").html(@view.el)
@view.render()
```

Now when you render your template, it is actually on the page before jwplayer tries to find that element.

Comment: DUDE!  Thank you so much!  I spent an entire day working on this!  Is there any drawback to doing it this way? Like, why isn't this the default way to set the router up?

Comment: I can't think of any drawbacks... I don't know anything about jwplayer but I imagine it is looking for the element using `document.getElementById`. And when you render the view before adding it to the page, jwplayer can't find it yet.  You could also do something like `$("#videos").html(@view.render().el); @view.setupJWPlayer()`

Comment: Cool man, I really appreciate your help. And I do believe your guess as to what jwplayer is doing is correct.